# Load data from firebase to amazon redshift

Tags: database, firebase, amazon-redshift

I have around 500MB data in firebase and I want to move it to amazon redshift on daily basis. what is the best way for above problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: we're missing your code and errors your getting. please read How to ask stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

What is "the best way" depends on your criteria, and often highly subjective. But a few pointers may help you get started:

- **don't** download the entire data with a single `ref.once('value'`. Loading that much data will take time and all your regular users will be blocked while your read is being fulfilled.
- **do** consider using [Firebase's private backups](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html). These are coming out of a different data stream, so will not interfere with your regular users. But the downside is that you'll need to a [paid app](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html) to be able to use this feature.
- **do** consider how you can make your backup process streaming, instead of daily. Firebase is a real-time database, and typically works best when you consider the data flow to be real-time too.